# aws cli describe cluster error using 'for loop'

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, sh, aws-cli

I'm having trouble trying to run a for loop with the aws cli command **aws eks describe-cluster**. I receive the below error on execution. My scripting is not the best. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
for i in $(aws eks list-clusters | grep dev-shark); do aws eks describe-cluster --name $i | jq '.cluster.tags."Dev-Ver"'; done

An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the DescribeCluster operation: The name parameter contains invalid characters. It should begin with letter or digit and can have any of the following characters: the set of Unicode letters, digits, hyphens and underscores.
```

If I simply run **aws eks list-clusters | grep dev-shark** it outputs the below:

```
aws eks list-clusters | grep dev-shark

"dev-shark-01-eks-cluster",  
"dev-shark-02-eks-cluster",  
"dev-shark-03-eks-cluster"
```

It seems to be the comma (,) that is causing the error? How best to remove the , at the end of each line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is both the comma (,) and the quotation mark (") that are causing the error. Instead of doing

```
aws eks list-clusters | grep dev-shark
```

, you can do

```
aws eks list-clusters --query 'clusters' --output text | tr '\t' '\n' | grep dev-shark
```

Comment: @jellysc brilliant!!! that has got rid of the comma , but I'm receiving a bad substitution per below message. 

for i in ${aws eks list-clusters --query 'clusters' --output text | tr '\t' '\n' | dev-shark}; do aws eks describe-cluster --name $i | jq '.cluster.tags."Dev-Ver"'; done

bash: ${aws eks list-clusters --query 'clusters' --output text | tr '\t' '\n' | grep dev-shark}: bad substitution

Comment: I've created a separate post/question to follow up with the second error. Thanks for your help @jellycsc

Comment: @BigRed247 you forgot `grep` in front of `dev-shark`